# MySql, "group by" output columns instead of rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot-table

I have a table like this,

```
+----------------+
| id | name|type |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  |  J  |  A  |
| 2  |  S  |  A  |
| 3  |  S  |  B  |
| 4  |  S  |  B  |
| 5  |  J  |  B  |
| 6  |  J  |  C  |
+----+-----+-----+
```

id is Primary Key, name's value are not certain, but type's value can only be A, B or C.
Want to build a MySql view, which means a SELECT, to output following table, which count different types by name.

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| name| countOfTypeA | countOfTypeB | countOfTypeC |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  J  |  1           | 1            |  1           |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  S  |  1           | 2            |  0           |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Tried "Group by name, type" but it output types in rows not in columns.
Please help.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Exactly as what  Bill Karwin pointed out, the answer of question "MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns" did answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: select t.n, 
 count(case when t.t = 'A' THEN 1 END) A,
    count(case when t.t = 'B' THEN 1 END) B,
    count(case when t.t = 'C' THEN 1 END) C
FROM test as t
group by t.n;